# ASP.NET: Building a Chart Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

Greetings fellow developers. I am developing a chart control in reference to https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150803/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102809-1.aspx.

I am facing an error (Non-invocable member 'Series.Point' cannot be used like a method). Can anyone guide me in resolving this issue?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        //Reference the Year series 
        Series yearseries = Chart1.Series["C"];

        DataView results = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        foreach(DataRowView row in results)
        {
            //Add a datapoint
            yearseries.Points.AddXY(row["Year"], row["Amount"]);
            //Get the just added point
        DataPoint justAddedPoint = yearseries.Points(yearseries.Points.Count - 1);

            justAddedPoint.Url = string.Format("Admin_Stats.aspx?Year={0}", row["Year"].ToString());
        }


    }
```

What I've tried:

- Adding namespace called System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting, but can't be used.
- Tried searching it in the References but kept coming empty.

Comment: Which line is the error occurring in?

Comment: The line after my comment (//Get the just added point) @mason

Comment: Well see, you say that, but your error message is saying there's a problem with "Series.Point" while your line of code shows "Points". Those are not the same thing, are you sure that the error message and code you have provided was exactly what you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure the compiler is complaining about …

```
yearseries.Points(yearseries.Points.Count - 1)
```

`Points` is a “collection” and you are trying to reference it like a method.

You want to reference the “index” into the `Points` collection.

Therefore, change the open/close “()” with brackets “[]” … like …

```
yearseries.Points[yearseries.Points.Count – 1]
```